# How to override specific syntax rules for XML in vim?

Tags: xml, vim, macvim

In vim my html has end-tags highlighted the same as start tags, my XML does not:

[image]

I understand this is a problem with the theme I'm using which is this:

https://github.com/flazz/vim-colorschemes/blob/master/colors/codeschool.vim

But I'm not sure how to go about tracking down what to change, and where to override it. I would like the end tags to match the start tags.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. When you have the name of the offending syntax group, you can investigate where it comes from; (the last lines of) `:scriptnames` may help.

In XML, the start tag is highlighted by `xmlTag` and `xmlTagName`, whereas the end tag is highlighted by `xmlEndTag`. Usually, all three are linked to the built-in `Identifier` highlight group. You can investigate where this got changed via:

```
:verbose hi xmlEndTag
xmlEndTag      xxx links to Identifier
    Last set from /usr/local/share/vim/vim80/syntax/xml.vim
```